# numpy in Python 3.6: Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.6

Can anyone help me with this error? I don't have any older versions of numpy, and i installed it using pip, i get 1.13.0 version of numpy and I'm working on Windows 10 OS. Any suggestions?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Asus/PycharmProjects/g/num.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: what's the command that you are using to install `numpy`?

Comment: pip install numpy, uninstalled and tried pip3.6 install numpy

Comment: Have a look at the answer below

Answer (score 3):

You are, apparently, a victim of [issue  9272](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9272). `numpy` is built against Python `3.6.1` but you're using Python `3.6.0`.

Based on the discussion there, you should just upgrade to Python 3.6.1 to get it to work. It does seem like they will build on `3.6.0` too, though, follow that issue to keep track of that.